# Disable select option in group of select dropdowns when option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, drop-down-menu

What I'm trying to do: I have multiple select dropdowns, if an option is selected in one of the select dropdowns and the value exists in any of the other dropdowns the value should be disabled/unselectable, it again can become enabled/selectable if the selection is changed.

What happens with current code: it works about 50%, I can't pinpoint the issue, but I think because I'm applying a for loop some values get skipped and not disabled and sometimes the "Select" default option becomes disabled?!

Approach: The way I wrote my code was when a selection from the dropdown box occurs, enable all options, get the first dropdown's current selected value, if it's not the default "Select" then go through every dropdown box and disable any matching values, then repeat this process for the second dropdown's current selected value and so on.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/haakym/r2y73ndt/

Code:
HTML:

```
<div id="nomineeInfo">
<div>
    <label>Manager</label>
    <select class="positionTypes" id="pos_manager">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">John Smith</option>
        <option value="2">Jane Smith</option>
        <option value="4">John Smoe</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Deputy</label>
    <select class="positionTypes" id="pos_deputy_manager">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">John Smith</option>
        <option value="2">Jane Smith</option>
        <option value="3">John Doe</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Finance</label>
    <select class="positionTypes" id="pos_finance">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">John Smith</option>
        <option value="3">John Doe</option>
        <option value="4">John Smoe</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#nomineeInfo').on('change', '.positionTypes', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var dropdownOnChangeId = $(this).prop('id');
    var positionTypesEn = ['manager', 'deputy_manager', 'finance'];

    // set all enabled
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        $('#pos_'+positionTypesEn[i]).each(function(){
            $("option", this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        // if position type selected value is not 0, i.e. if it's not "Select"
        if( $('#pos_' + positionTypesEn[i]).val() != 0 ){
            // go through each option in every dropdown
            for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                console.log( positionTypesEn[j] ); // show current dropdown
                $('#pos_' + positionTypesEn[j] + ' option').each(function(k){

                    if( !$(this).is(':selected') ){ 
                        if( $(this).val() == selectedValue && $(this).val() != 0 ){
                            $(this).prop('disabled', 'true');
                            console.log('disabled: ' +  $(this).val() );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that you enable everything at the beginning. So if something is disabled because you selected it in the first menu, then you select something from the second menu, that will re-enable the option from the first menu.

Comment: Right, I thought because I would be checking every selected item after enabling all, not only the one that changed, this wouldn't be an issue. Will be sure to check why this wasn't working. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After enabling all the options, you need to go through all the menus, get their selected values, and re-disable all of them in the other menus, not just the one you just changed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nomineeInfo').on('change', '.positionTypes', function () {
        // Get the selected options of all positions
        var allSelected = $(".positionTypes").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        // set all enabled
        $(".positionTypes option").removeAttr("disabled");

        // Disable selected options in other positions
        $(".positionTypes option:not(:selected):not([value='0'])").each(function () {
            if ($.inArray($(this).val(), allSelected) != -1) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r2y73ndt/5/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("select.positionTypes").change(function () {
    $("select.positionTypes option").prop('disabled', false);
    $("select.positionTypes option:selected:not([value='0'])").each(function (i) {
        $("select.positionTypes option:nth-child(" + ((+this.value) + 1) + ")").prop('disabled', true)
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2y73ndt/7/)

Comment: @haakym Did you check my demo ..Is this u expected ?

Comment: You have the same problem as the original code. When you select something from menu 1, it's disabled in menus 2 and 3. Then when you select something from menu 3, the choice from menu 1 becomes enabled everywhere again.

Comment: Also, when you use `:nth-child`, you're assuming that the values are always sequential. Look at the HTML in his question, the values are `0, 1, 2, 4` in some of the menus.

Comment: @Barmar Please have a look at my answer once again. :) I understood the concept clearly now.

Comment: Seems to work just fine, but already accepted Barmar's answer thank you for your answer. I will definitely analyse the code later.

Comment: Worth noting to others your answer works based on each value in the dropdown list being in sequential order as Barmar pointed out earlier.

Comment: @haakym Check out the optimized version. I had posted it as a separate one, no loops required, no arrays required.. just the magic of selectors. :) :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this too, an optimized version

```
$("select.positionTypes").change(function () {
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value='0'])").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2y73ndt/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure, classes and attempt is not bad but if you are using jQuery you should use its full advantages like .each function to make your live alot easier.

I would make an attempt like this:

```
$('.positionTypes').on('change', function () { //When any select changes...
    var changedID = $(this).attr("id"); //Save id of select that was changed...
    var selectedValue = $(this).val(); //Save value of select was changed...
    if($(this).val() != "0") { //If we did not select a 0 value at all...
        $('.positionTypes option').prop("disabled", false); //Enable all disabled options of all selects...
        $('.positionTypes').each(function() { //Loop all existing selects
            if($(this).attr("id") != changedID) { //If the select id is not our own select
                $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " option").each(function() { //loop all options of all selects except the one excluded by previous if clause
                    if($(this).attr("value") == selectedValue) { //if the value matches to saved value
                        $(this).prop("disabled", true); //Disable this one
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I am not sure if this is 100% complete atleast it can disable options of other selects with identical value with a little bit more structured code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, doesn't seem to function 100% as you said, will check out your approach later. Thank you for your answer sir.